Typescript and passing parameters using super() through extended classes
My UserNotFoundException class extends from HttpException to help manage exception errors in a project.
The original HttpException class constructor expects the status number and message string.
class HttpException extends Error {
  public status: number;
  public override message: string;

  constructor(status: number, message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export default HttpException;

I'm passing a user id as an argument for UserNotFoundException to then respond with the error. To support the extends super() and original class UserNotFoundException is extending from, I'm passing the constructer arguments from HttpException, status and message.
import HttpException from './HttpException.js';

class UserNotFoundException extends HttpException {
  constructor(id: string) {
    super(404, `User with id ${id} not found`);
  }
}

export default UserNotFoundException;


Up to this point, my IDE is showing everything good until the API request handler tries to handle the UserNotFoundException() exception.
  private getUserById = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const id = request.params["id"];

    // Simulate finding a user
    const user = this.user._id === id ? this.user : null;
    if (user) {
      response.send(user);
    } else {
      // My IDE says Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
      next(new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }
  };

Why is UserNotFoundException(id) not able interpret that I am passing the original constructer arguments in the super() statement of the class.
UserNotFoundExcption is expecting
UserNotFoundException(status: number, message: string)

not
UserNotFoundException(id: string)

its as if this constructer is doing nothing:
  constructor(id: string) {
    super(404, `User with id ${id} not found`);
  }

Error im getting:
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
HttpException.ts(5, 31): An argument for 'message' was not provided.

Appreciate if someone can tell me what im doing wrong.

Are you sure the error is for the constructor call, not for the next function?

Hi @smac89, can you explain a little more? My IDE Is highlighting new UserNotFoundException(id). I have also posted the exact error in bottom of my original post.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where we can see what you're seeing in our own IDEs. When I look at your code, the new UserNotFoundException(id) does not have a compiler error (although there are plenty of other errors because it's just an excerpt of code referring to undeclared things). If we can't reproduce it, then it's hard to help (and might be closed as needing debugging details).

Can you double-check the import line for UserNotFoundException? When it's a default export, it's easy to accidentally name it the wrong thing (I know I've caught myself out this way).
